# Regular Expression for checking if a string contains atleas one [a-z] & [0-9, Two [A-Z] and the length of entire string should be 4 to 10 CHARS

Tags: regex

Regular Expression for checking if a string contains at least one `[a-z]` & `[0-9]`. Two `[A-Z]` and the length of entire stringenter code here should be 4 to 10 CHARS.

I've been trying this for long...but am not able to.

Comment: Just do it in code, it's about 3 lines. Your coworkers will thank you.

Comment: I had been asked this question in an interview and couldn't answer it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/^(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[A-Z].*?[A-Z]).{4,10}$/
```

However, doing the four tests separately with single regexes or `getStringLength()` would be much more readable and maintainable.